# Unable to resolve IDbContext while activating Service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, service, cqrs, mediatr

Working in CQRS with MediatR, in Startup I register the DomainEventDispatcher, the Repos, Query- and Eventhandlers and the Services.
The repos work with DbContext and so do my services. Everything CRUD works until I inject my Service in the Controller,
I get the following error: 
Unable to resolve service for type 'IDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Service'.

I Find it strange seeing as I

```
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
      {
        options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(cs);
        options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
      });
```

before registering the following:

```
services
.AddScoped<IDomainEventsDispatcher, DomainEventsDispatcher>()
.AddScoped<IRepo<ToDoItem>, EfCRepo<ToDoItem>>()
.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.AsScoped(), typeof(ToDoItemsQueryHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
.AddScoped<INotificationHandler<Event>, EventHandler>()
.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.AsScoped(), typeof(EventHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
.AddScoped<IService, Service>()
```

When I try to AddScoped the IDbContext with the

```
AddScoped<IDbContext, DbContext>()
```

My Context is empty and cannot Get entities from Db anymore.

I find it strange that I would need to AddScoped the IDbContext for the services, 
seeing as the Repos work with the DbContext as well, without needing to resolve service for type IDbContext.

I've looked at MediatR official documentation and couldn't find anything on how to register Services,
and googling 'register services MediatR startup' redirects mostly to other issues, 
so any help/insights from you guys is more than welcome!

I've made a new question as I can dependency inject, but somehow seems different for services. Most questions on S/O regarding registering in startup are more generic to my feeling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One of the dependencies in teh objecrt graph explicitly depends in `IDbContext`. And since the container is unaware of that type it wont know how to resolve its implementation for injection.

Comment: Do `services.AddDbContext<IDbContext, DbContext>` instead.

Comment: Thankyou for the pointer & sanityCheck @Nkosi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future references:
The solution was indeed to add

```
AddScoped<IDbContext, DbContext>()
```

Must have been something else that broke my context